# How does stripos and str_replace work?

Tags: php, str-replace, stripos

I am struggling to understand how the php functions `stripos` and `str_replace` work.

I have a body of text such as : `{% if group.newt !== "" %} XYZ's {% else %} ABC's {% endif %}`

and am wanting to replace that text with `Go to this link www.google.com`.

I search through the bodies of text:

`if(stripos($entity->getBodyOfText(), $strTFind) !== false)
{preg_match("{% if group.newt !== "" %} XYZ's {% else %} ABC's {% endif %}", $strToReplace)};`

OR

`$str_replace($strToFind, $strToReplace, $entity->getBodyOfText());`

The results I am getting are that the text is not being found or replaced! I do not understand why. Could someone please shed light on this for me?

EDIT:

The body of text is an email template with lots of images, text, and twig code. In a particular set of email templates, I need to find and replace a whole block of twig code with one line of text (it doesn't matter what that text is). The problem I'm having is when I search for the block of code in the email templates using `str_replace` or `preg_replace`, those functions do not find or replace the block I am trying to find and replace.

So my output is the same (nothing is found, nothing is changed).

For example:

```
    `here would be an image 

    now starts a heading,

      some more text with {{ twig.variable }} and then more text.
    more

    text, lots more text some {% twig.fucntions %}blah{% ending %} and 
then here is the block 
I want to find and replace: {% replace this whole thing including the brackets and percentage signs %}keep replacing
{% else %}
replace that else (everything including the brackets and percentage signs)and
{% this too %}.

    some more ending text.

    image,

    the end`
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: What is a small example of the full string that has the `{% ... %}` substring inside of it?

Comment: it's twig code..."{% if statements !== "" %}this should show{% else %}another thing shows{% endif %}".

Comment: I am unfamiliar with twig code.  When I try to help other users with str/preg replace type questions, I like to see a clear explanation of what the full input is, what they are targeting as a substring, and what is going in its place.  I see that you want the link string to go in, but the rest is unclear.  Please show the full before and after texts, so that your question is crystal clear.  Is there any more text outside of the twig expression?

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace...

```
str_replace("Pattern to search",$stringToSearch,"Replacement text");
```

So in practice:

```
$string = "{% if group.newt !== '' %} XYZ's {% else %} ABC's {% endif %}";

$newString = str_replace("{% if group.newt !== '' %} XYZ's {% else %} ABC's {% endif %}",$string,"Go to this link www.google.com");

echo $newString;
```

Fyi, you'll need to href that link for it to be an actual link though. Also fixed your "" in your comparison to be '' to accommodate PHP encasing with " ";

Tested in PhpFiddle.com

If you plan to use your function

```
$entity->getBodyOfText();
```

replace $string with that, OR assign

```
$string = $entity->getBodyOfText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a non-regex solution requires that you know exactly the substring you are trying to replace -- I'll assume you know the substring.  A word of caution, if there is any chance of the substring occurring more than once and you only want one replacement, then `str_replace()` will fail you by replacing all found substrings.  If the substring will be unique in the string, or you would like to replace all duplicate substrings, then everything will work as intended.

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e6928d1d9ce41bcaa32ccf098521d3cbd013908)):

```
$find='{% replace this whole thing including the brackets and percentage signs %}keep replacing
{% else %}
replace that else (everything including the brackets and percentage signs)and
{% this too %}.';
$replace='LINK';

$text=str_replace($find,$replace,$text);
echo "$text";
```

Output:

```
here would be an image 

    now starts a heading,

      some more text with {{ twig.variable }} and then more text.
    more

    text, lots more text some {% twig.fucntions %}blah{% ending %} and 
then here is the block 
I want to find and replace: LINK

    some more ending text.

    image,

    the end
```

If you need a better tailored solution, please explain how this method is failing you and I'll adjust it.

Comment: @grgre Please give me some feedback about my two attempts.  If I am still dead wrong, please try again to explain your question to me.  If my patterns don't adequately accommodate all of your possible twig code syntaxes, please provide an additional input sample for me to test against.  If either of these methods are what you are looking for, let me know which one you want to use so I can delete the other.

Comment: Please check my edit, I hope that'll help you understand better. Your answers now will not work for me.

Comment: @grge I updated my answer.  If this doesn't help, again, please leave me a comment.